# Why is the on message event working for a few minutes then it stops working?

Tags: python, discord.py

okay I know for the past few days this is all I have been posting about but I am curious on why my `on_message` command works for a few times then it stops all of a sudden here I will show you my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=None)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("ready!")
  
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('<:SF1:763564017456644116> sign'):
    role = get(message.guild.roles, name='San Francisco 49ers')
    member = message.mentions[0]
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} **Successfully signed to** <:SF1:763564017456644116>')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('<:ATL1:763564014344208414> sign'):
    role = get(message.guild.roles, name='Atlanta Falcons')
    member = message.mentions[0]
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} **Successfully signed to** <:ATL1:763564014344208414>')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('<:CAR1:763564014478819378> sign'):
    role = get(message.guild.roles, name='Carolina Panthers')
    member = message.mentions[0]
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} **Successfully signed to** <:CAR1:763564014478819378>')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('<:DAL1:763564014843592714> sign'):
    role = get(message.guild.roles, name='Dallas Cowboys')
    member = message.mentions[0]
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} **Successfully signed to** <:DAL1:763564014843592714>')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('<:DET1:763564015057764362> sign'):
    role = get(message.guild.roles, name='Detroit Lions')
    member = message.mentions[0]
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} **Successfully signed to** <:DET1:763564015057764362>')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

so this is what is happening in picture form:

here is the first time I tested:
[image]

and the second time I test it:
[image]

can someone please help explain to me what I am doing incorrectly so I can fix it?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the second screenshot?

Comment: Oops my bad I screenshotted it twice on accident... what happened was instead of the bot replying the way it. It just did nothing no message.

Comment: also I read on this github post, I was wondering if  `await bot.process_commands(message)` would make it run more consistently?

Comment: You've defined `on_message` six times. All but one of them will be overwritten. Try putting all your code in one statement.

Comment: like so remove the `@client.event` except leave one?

Comment: or remove the `on_message` and just start from at the if statement

Comment: Yeah the answer below is correct I believe

Answer (score 0):

You can just put them all in 1 on_message instead of separating them like that.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('<:SF1:763564017456644116> sign'):
        role = get(message.guild.roles, name='San Francisco 49ers')
        member = message.mentions[0]
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} **Successfully signed to** <:SF1:763564017456644116>')
    if message.content.startswith('<:ATL1:763564014344208414> sign'):
        role = get(message.guild.roles, name='Atlanta Falcons')
        member = message.mentions[0]
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} **Successfully signed to** <:ATL1:763564014344208414>')
    if message.content.startswith('<:CAR1:763564014478819378> sign'):
        role = get(message.guild.roles, name='Carolina Panthers')
        member = message.mentions[0]
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} **Successfully signed to** <:CAR1:763564014478819378>')
    if message.content.startswith('<:DAL1:763564014843592714> sign'):
        role = get(message.guild.roles, name='Dallas Cowboys')
        member = message.mentions[0]
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} **Successfully signed to** <:DAL1:763564014843592714>')
    if message.content.startswith('<:DET1:763564015057764362> sign'):
        role = get(message.guild.roles, name='Detroit Lions')
        member = message.mentions[0]
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} **Successfully signed to** <:DET1:763564015057764362>')
```

you could also put the `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of each event

Docs: [process_commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process_commands#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)